# Passing around ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java

Is it a good practice to pass around a concurrent hashmap to other methods? So I have a lookup map which is a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>()` which I need to use in different methods within the class to look up whether it contains an object or not. Currently, I create this map and pass this to the functions for lookup purpose for eg, `public Data getData(ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> map)`. Is this a bad practice? If this is not ideal, can anyone suggest a safer/better way? That said, the module I am working on is something similar to a file upload, so multiple users can upload the file at the same time.

------- Follow up --> So when my method gets the call `get(Resources r)` I create a ConcurrentHashMap and put all the resources/objects that I create into this map, in order to look it up in other functions. For this reason, I pass `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> map` to another function `createObj(ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> map)` and then from there I would again further pass this map to another function. Here is a small snippet to make the question clearer. Is it okay to do as below?

```
Class Data {

final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
map.put("1", person);
map.put("2", person);

Address a = getAddress(map);

public Address getAddress(ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> map){
Person p = map.get("1");
boolean isAlive = getPersonAbove50(map);
return p.getAddress();
}
```

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with passing a resource to a method to do something but it may indicate a design flaw if you are repeatedly passing this one thing as an argument - perhaps each of these consumers should have a reference to this Map rather than requiring it to be passed it as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, question updated. So what you mean is the function that accepts this concurrenthashMap should be doing like this `Map map = new HashMap<>(concurrenthashMap);` and then use `map` pass it further down to other methods as required?

Comment: That isn't passing the map around.  That is making a copy of the concurrent hash map entries ... as a HashMap.   And it isn't what vsfDawg meant ... I think.  The problem is that your question is too high level / abstract / lacking in details.

Comment: By the way ... you really are asking for opinions ("thoughts"), and questions that ask for opinions are off-topic.

Comment: Hi @StephenC I have updated the question. How differently should it be done according to what vsfDawg's response?

Comment: Basically he is saying "don't pass the map around as a parameter".   I'm not sure I agree with that, but ... hey ... this is an opinion question.  Your example is too small and too artificial to discuss in terms of so-called "best practice" or "bad practice".  And "practice" questions are opinion based anyway.